# How to get all combinations of n binary values where number of 1's are equal to or more than the number of 0's?

Tags: python, python-itertools

I want to find a list of all possible combinations of 0's and 1's. The only condition is that the number of 1's must be more than or equal to the number of 0's. For example for `n = 4` the output should be something like this:

```py
[(0, 0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 0, 1), (0, 1, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1, 1), (1, 0, 0, 1), (1, 0, 1, 0), (1, 0, 1, 1), (1, 1, 0, 0), (1, 1, 0, 1), (1, 1, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1, 1)]
```

Is there an elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `distinct_permutations`:

```
from more_itertools import distinct_permutations

def get_combos(n):
    for i in range((n+1)//2, n + 1):
        for permutation in distinct_permutations([1] * i + [0] * (n - i), n):
            yield permutation
print(list(get_combos(4)))
# [(0, 0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 0, 1), (0, 1, 1, 0), (1, 0, 0, 1), (1, 0, 1, 0), (1, 1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 1, 1), (1, 0, 1, 1), (1, 1, 0, 1), (1, 1, 1, 0)]
```

Here, we simply consider the permutations of each sublist:

```
[0, 0, 1, 1]
[0, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Notice that for large `n`, the `yield` statement is very useful because you do not generate all permutations at once.

We need to use `distinct_permutations` because you use just 1's and 0's , so regular permutations will give you repeated elements.

---

If you don't want to install another library, you can use:

```
from itertools import permutations

def get_combos(n):
    for i in range(n // 2 if n%2 == 0 else n//2 + 1, n):
        for permutation in permutations([1] * i + [0] * (n - i), n):
            yield permutation
print(set(get_combos(4)))
# {(0, 1, 0, 1), (0, 1, 1, 1), (1, 0, 1, 1), (1, 1, 0, 0), (1, 1, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1, 0), (1, 0, 1, 0), (1, 0, 0, 1), (1, 1, 0, 1), (0, 0, 1, 1)}
```

as `set` will eliminate the repeated elements, at the cost of needing to process the entire set of permutations at once (ie., by calling `set`, you will consume the entire generator immediately, rather than drawing elements from it as you need them).

### More details on distinct_permutations

It might not be clear why these are needed. Consider this list:

```
[1, 2]
```

permutations, by default, will tell you that all the permutations of this list are

```
(1, 2)
```

and

```
(2, 1)
```

However, `permutations` doesn't bother checking what the elements are or if they are repeated, so it simply performs the swap as above and if  the list is

```
[1, 1]
```

you'll get back

```
[(1, 1), (1, 1)]
```

Comment: nit: maybe `math.ceil(n / 2)` instead of `n // 2 if n%2 == 0 else n//2 + 1`?  Or if for some reason you wanted to avoid `math.ceil`, `n // 2 + n % 2` would provide the same result a little more succinctly.

Comment: @Samwise: Simpler is either `(n + 1) // 2` (the C way) or `-(-n // 2)` (the Python way that works thanks to guaranteed floor, not truncating, division), both of which get the ceiling of `n` divided by `2` without converting to `float` midway.

Comment: Note: You can simplify even further by replacing the explicit inner loop with an implicit one: `yield from permutations([1] * i + [0] * (n - i), n)`

Comment: The `permutations` one seems very slow, unless n is very small. And you don't need to give it n as argument, as you want *all* permutations and it does that by default.

Answer (score 2):

Building up on @Kraigolas excellent answer, we can even simplify the entire process by building one single initial list containing `n // 2` zeros (`0`) and `n` ones (`1`). We then get the `distinct permutations` of length `n` only from that initial list

So for `n = 4` we return distinct permutation of size 4 from the following list: `[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]`

```py
from more_itertools import distinct_permutations


def get_combos(n):
    return distinct_permutations([0] * (n // 2) + [1] * n, n)
    
    
print(list(get_combos(4)))
# [(0, 0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 0, 1), (0, 1, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1, 1), (1, 0, 0, 1), (1, 0, 1, 0), (1, 0, 1, 1), (1, 1, 0, 0), (1, 1, 0, 1), (1, 1, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1, 1)]
```

Comment: I just finally realized what you're doing. Very nice. Could be fast, at least if `distinct_permutations` were implemented in C.

Comment: @KellyBundy from the timings I made, it's unfortunately about as slow as the accepted answer (about 9.3 seconds to generate permutations for n=24 on my Intel Core i7-4790K 4.00GHz). But the code is a bit more compact.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `itertools.product` and filter (you keep at least half of them, so it's not that wasteful):

```
from itertools import product

def get_combos(n):
    minimum = -(-n // 2)
    return [p
            for p in product([0, 1], repeat=n)
            if sum(p) >= minimum]

print(get_combos(4))
```

(Might be faster to use `p.count(1)`.)

Or `itertools.combinations` for choosing k of the n indexes to set to 0:

```
from itertools import combinations

def get_combos(n):
    for k in range(n//2 + 1):
        for indexes in combinations(range(n), k):
            combo = [1] * n
            for i in indexes:
                combo[i] = 0
            yield tuple(combo)

print(list(get_combos(4)))
```